# Modify routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm a new user of rails so it's complicated to understand how the `routes.rb` works! So I try to modify a route, I got a path that look like this:
`user/:id/edit` but i want that the id not appear in the path.

I try to use this method :

```
get '/users/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'users/edit'
```

but it changes nothing. In my `routes.rb` i got :

```
resources :users,  only: [:create, :new, :show, :edit]
```

Someone know how to do this? I already take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want the user id present. If you have numerous users it makes your app more RESTful and you can put in validations so users can only edit their own accounts. Could you also put up your code for your routes.rb. Also when you say it changes nothing, what do you mean by that? Do you get a particular error or do the routes remain unchanged?

Comment: @AlexanderSwann Singular resources are perfectly restful.

Comment: Ah okay! Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have taken,

```
resources :users
```

Now change this route as follows,

```
get '/users/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'users_edit'
```

Now in your view file where you have `edit link`, change the link to,

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', users_edit_path(:id => user.id) %>
```

Now this links to the edit action of users controller with an `id parameter`.

Now, in the users controller file,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def edit

    // params[:id] will be the ID that you sent through the view file.
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

end
```

Thats it, you are done with your custom route, now the route will be `users/edit instead of users/:id/edit`

Answer (score 2):

If you already take a look at guides, do you read about [`singular resources?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without
>   referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show
>   the profile of the currently logged in user. **In this case, you can use
>   a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the
>   show action**:

```
resource :geocoder
```

creates six different routes in your application, all mapping to the Geocoders controller:

```
GET          /geocoder/new  geocoders#new   return an HTML form for creating the geocoder
POST         /geocoder  geocoders#create    create the new geocoder
GET          /geocoder  geocoders#show  display the one and only geocoder resource
GET          /geocoder/edit geocoders#edit  return an HTML form for editing the geocoder
PATCH/PUT    /geocoder  geocoders#update    update the one and only geocoder resource
DELETE       /geocoder  geocoders#destroy   delete the geocoder resource
```

Comment: Thank you! I modify my routes.rb adding the resource geocoder and modify my route like this : get '/users', to: :show, controller: 'users'
but i got an error, No route matches [GET] "/users/1/edit" so my program try to find the old path how can I change it?

Comment: @maluss change the `*_path` helper.